# QGIS dissolves all different shapes into one feature instead of multiple features

Tags: qgis, buffer, dissolve

I'm pretty new to QGIS and geoprocessing. I have a layer of points representing traffic lights - where each point is a different feature:
[image: Traffic lights layer]

I wish to create a layer with traffic light junctions based on this layer. My approach is to create buffer around each point - which I've done using QGIS:
[image: Buffered points]

But then, when I try yo dissolve them into single shapes, QGIS creates one feature for all the shapes instead of a feature per junction:
[image: Dissolved shapes - all on a single feature]

How can I tell QGIS to create a feature per junction?

Comment: You can either dissolve on a "junction ID", or dissolve all polygons into 1 then change the layer from multi-part to single part

Comment: On a side note, the buffer seems to have been created using lat-longs, resulting in the ellipse shape. Since a degree of longitude has not the same ground length, in meters, as a degree of latitude, it is best to use a projected coordinate system before working with distances

Comment: Thank you! Multipoint to single point did the job.
You comment about distances is correct, but I'm still experimenting with the capabilities before diving into the projected coordinate system.